# Downloading online text with different encodings

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am downloading online text, that can be uploaded by users, so texts can be UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc...

The problem is that i don't know wich encoding are using the users, and if the user has uploaded a UTF-8 text it works perfect but if the user has uploaded a ISO-8859-1 text with accents (á é etc..) these characters are not shown correctly.

I tryed to force text encoding to UTF-8 but it not works for all the cases (buffer.toString("UTF-8"))

this is my code:

```
javaUrl = new URL(URLParser.parse(textResource.getUrlStr()));
                    connection = javaUrl.openConnection();                      
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int nRead;
                    try{        
                        byte [] data = new byte [1024];
                        while ((nRead = input.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                        }
                        buffer.flush();
                        total = buffer.toString();                  
                    }finally{
                        input.close();
                        buffer.close();
                    }
```

Comment: You have a lot of problems with your handling of resources to start with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple possible encodings and you don't know which is correct you have little choice but to use a `CharsetDecoder` here.

The plan:

- open the `InputStream` from the connection;
- read all contents into a `byte[]` array;
- try with the different encodings until you find a suitable one.

Here is one possible method to find the correct encoding:

```
public boolean isCharset(final Charset charset, final byte[] contents)
    throws IOException
{
    final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder()
        .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(contents);

    try {
        decoder.decode(buf);
        return true;
    } catch (CharacterCodingException ignored) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Try this with a different set of encodings (preferrably starting with UTF-8).

Comment: i need to achieve this without external third party libraries like Guava

Comment: how can be used your function? give me an example of parameter calling please

Comment: ok i tryed with isCharset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"),  buffer.toByteArray()) and it seems it is working, now i must check each possible charset until i find a true and then parse the string to that charset?

Comment: So, uhm, do you mean you actually want the string result? And what do you do with that result, then?

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. If it is true i force encoding to that encoding, and works fine, thanks

Comment: Rather than guessing the charset, why not use the charset that is reported by the server? If the file is being downloaded via HTTP, type-cast the `connection` to [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and call its `getHeaderFieldKey()` and `getHeaderField()` methods to find the `Content-Type` header and extract its `charset` attribute. The server should report the charset of the text it is sending. In the case of HTML files, if there is no `charset` in the `Content-Type` header, the HTML itself might have a `<meta>` tag for the charset.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is true, and this should be the preferred charset; however, in some situations you either don't have this header, or this header is lying...